# Why should I use the word "we" instead of "I" in scientific papers written alone?

Tags: grammar, formal-language

In many scientific articles there are sentences of the form "In this paper we will show ..." For me that sounds natural if there are many authors. But if a researchers writes an article such that she is the only author, why she might also write "In this paper we will show ..." instead of "In this paper I will show ..." Is it because she uses other results that someone else has achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different academic or scientific journals have different criteria on this issue. Some insist on use of the third person or passive voice, whereas others allow first person such as "we", although the use of the individual personal pronoun "I" is usually frowned upon.

https://unilearning.uow.edu.au/academic/3avi.html